# Dynamic delimiter in DFDL

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

In DFDL of a delimited file in IIB, is it possible to make the delimiter as dynamic? Or is it possible to override the Separator of a DFDL while writing out a delimited file?

Comment: I'd be rather interested to see a sample string. I'd be rather surprised if the delimiters occur in a truly random manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have multiple options, you can create all these fields as optionnals in the DFDL, but if it is really dynamic, you can't do it with DFDL.

Since you are using IBM Integration Bus, I would suggest you to consider other approach :

- Use IBM Transformation eXtender (it is an additional license, but would perfectly match you requirements, also required knowledge)
- Use compute nodes (Java, ESQL, ... ) to create the file as a String